# libpytorch macos build: static library eigen_blas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND not found

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, static-libraries, eigen

When building a static libpytorch on macos, cmake configuration for `find_package` reports the following warning:

```
[cmake] CMake Warning at libtorch_from_source/pytorch-build/TorchConfig.cmake:22 (message):
[cmake]   static library eigen_blas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND not found.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   libtorch_from_source/pytorch-build/TorchConfig.cmake:113 (append_torchlib_if_found)
[cmake]   src/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

And the build later fails with link errors that look related to the missing library.

I build libpytorch with the following command (from the source directory):

```
mkdir pytorch-build && cd pytorch-build && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DUSE_CUDA=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=MinSizeRel -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=`which python3` -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=../pytorch-build ../pytorch && cmake --build . --target install
```

And this is the CMakeLists.txt that contains the `find_package`:

```
set(Torch_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libtorch_from_source/pytorch-build)
set(ENV{TORCH_INSTALL_PREFIX} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libtorch_from_source/pytorch-build)
find_package(Torch 1.8.0 EXACT REQUIRED)

add_executable(myexec main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexec  PRIVATE "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
target_include_directories(myexec PRIVATE "${TORCH_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

Comment: The `set(ENV{...})` command is definitely wrong and should just be `set(TORCH_INSTALL...)`. Regardless, when I tried to build, the experience was a mountain of errors and warnings culminating in an install directory that simply did not have all the dependencies.

Comment: `set` like that works just fine.
I had a similar experience with install directories.